# Skip environment post processor for spring starter

Tags: spring-boot, spring-autoconfiguration, post-processor

I am currently using spring boot with some 3rd parties starter. 
I want to disable those AutoConfiguration and the EnvironmentPostProcessor in the starter during testing 
I can disable AutoConfiguration by using `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude ={xxx}`, 
but cannot find any method to disable the EnvironmentPostProcessor. This blocks me from doing any test. Anyone can help?